# Current section not being highlighted correctly in nav when scrolling

Tags: jquery

I am creating a long page which has a navigation with anchor links. As you scroll down the page, the corresponding link in the nav will be highlighted to match the section you are on.

It works fine, however I also have a section on the page which does not have an anchor link in the nav. The trouble is, by adding this section, it ruins my section order, which ruins the correct selected state.

Here is a codepen to show you an example. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jEdKBp - Notice as you scroll down to the 'new section', the 'claims' link in the nav is highlighted, which is wrong!

What do I need to do so that only the current link is highlighted?

Here is my code...

HTML

```
    <nav id="prod-menu">
  <div class="wrapper">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#features">Features</a></li>
        <li><a href="#claims">Claims</a></li>
        <li><a href="#guides">Guides</a></li>
        <li><a href="#reviews">Reviews</a></li>
        <li><a href="#faq">FAQs</a></li>
      </ul>
  </div>
</nav> 


<section class="prod-hero"></section>

<div class="wrapper">

    <section class="tile js-panel pad0">        

        <section id="features" class="prod-panels"> 
            <h2>Features</h2>
        </section>

  <section class="prod-panels"> 
            <h2>New section</h2>
    <p>I do not want this section to appear in the nav</p>
        </section>

        <section id="claims" class="prod-panels">   
            <h2>Claims</h2>
        </section>

        <section id="guides" class="prod-panels">   
            <h2>Guides</h2>
        </section>

        <section id="reviews" class="prod-panels">  
            <h2>Reviews</h2>
        </section>

        <section id="faq" class="prod-panels">  
            <h2>FAQs</h2>
        </section>

    </section>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
var homeH = $( window ).height(),
    pH = [];
pH.push("0"); 

// create array with panel heights
for (var s=1; s<5; s++) { 
  var po = $(".js-panel section:nth-child("+s+")").position();
  pH.push( Math.round(po.top) );
};

$( window ).scroll(function() {      

  // toggle top menu selection
  for (var i=0;i<6;i++) {
    if ( $( window ).scrollTop() > pH[i]+900 ) { 
      $("#prod-menu ul li").removeClass("sel");
      $("#prod-menu ul li:nth-child("+(i+1)+")").addClass("sel");
     }
  };

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I decided to take a stab at this as well. I like to approach things like this with flexibility in mind, removing hard-coded values where I can, and taking into account a dynamic page flow. In my fork, instead of utilizing a class on the panels you want to link to the top-nav, I use the href and panel IDs to utilize the link that's implied by those matching.

```
var navPanels = $();
$('#prod-menu a').each(function() {
    navPanels = navPanels.add($(this.hash));    // easy array of nav panels according to nav items
});
```

Taking this approach, you can simply add or subtract nav items and panels without additional classes. Also, if they change height or move because another element above them in the stack causes the offset to change, having an array of offset().top values from the start will mismatch when scrolling, so that is checked on scroll. The offset check then becomes:

```
navPanels.each(function() {
    var $p = $(this)    // current panel in loop

    if ( $( window ).scrollTop() + $('#prod-menu').outerHeight() >= $p.offset().top) { 
        $("#prod-menu ul li").removeClass("sel");
        $('#prod-menu a').filter('[href="#'+$p.attr('id')+'"]').parent().addClass("sel");
    }
});
```

I am also accounting for the top nav height throughout the script so that your nav item is highlighted when the section scrolls past the viewable area, which starts beneath the top nav.

What this approach is not doing is removing highlighting for the section you don't want to show in nav. Instead, it's just leaving the nav before it highlighted.

This is the full JS:

```
$(function() {
    var homeH = $( window ).height(),
        navPanels = $();

    $('#prod-menu a').each(function() {
        navPanels = navPanels.add($(this.hash));    // easy array of nav panels according to nav items
    });

    $( window ).scroll(function() {
        // toggle top menu
        if ( $( window ).scrollTop() < homeH/2) {
            $("#prod-menu ul li").removeClass("sel");
            $("#prod-menu").css("top", ($('#prod-menu').outerHeight()*-1));
        } 
        else {
            $("#prod-menu").css("top", "0");
        };

        // toggle top menu selection
        navPanels.each(function() {
            var $p = $(this)    // current panel in loop

            if ( $( window ).scrollTop() + $('#prod-menu').outerHeight() >= $p.offset().top) { 
                $("#prod-menu ul li").removeClass("sel");
                $('#prod-menu a').filter('[href="#'+$p.attr('id')+'"]').parent().addClass("sel");
            }
        });
    });

    // animating anchor link scrolling
    // snippet from css-tricks 
    // css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/smooth-scrolling
    $("a[href*=#]:not([href=#])").click(function() {
        if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
            var target = $(this.hash);
            target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
            if (target.length) {
                $('html,body').animate({
                    scrollTop: target.offset().top-$('#prod-menu').outerHeight()
                }, 700);
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
});
```

The full Pen is here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MYNmbb

**EDIT**: *I am bored so I decided to expand on this.* If you want the nav to unhighlight when you scroll into a section that is not on the nav, you can change the "toggle top menu selection" function to the following, which is checking the bottom of the panel relative to the viewable area:

```
// toggle top menu selection
navPanels.each(function() {
    var $p = $(this)    // current panel in loop
    var viewTop = $( window ).scrollTop() + $('#prod-menu').outerHeight();
    if (viewTop  >= $p.offset().top) {
        $("#prod-menu ul li").removeClass("sel");
        if ($p.offset().top + $p.outerHeight() > viewTop) { 
            $('#prod-menu a').filter('[href="#'+$p.attr('id')+'"]').parent().addClass("sel");
        }
    }
});
```

Then, when you scroll into a section not in the nav, nothing is highlighted until you hit another section in the nav.

Again, full Pen is visible here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/emqWEW

Comment: Thank you for this. I voted this as the best answer as it was the least code and you also managed to take the highlight off the section which is not in the nav. I didn't even ask this but was thinking it!

Comment: It was a fun distraction. I was bored last night and wanted something to do so thank you for posting the question.

Answer (score 4):

I've changed some bits in your code and I hope this: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pvmXgK is what you want to have.

First I've changed the this line:

`var po = $(".js-panel section:nth-child("+s+")").position();`

to

`var po = $(".js-panel section.nav-section:eq("+s+")").offset();`

and added the class `nav-section` to all of the html sections that should are part of the navigation.

The toggle functionality is now splitted into two for loops but that might be not necessary. ;)

All code (without the css part)
**html**:

```
<nav id="prod-menu">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#features">Features</a></li>
      <li><a href="#claims">Claims</a></li>
      <li><a href="#guides">Guides</a></li>
      <li><a href="#reviews">Reviews</a></li>
      <li><a href="#faq">FAQs</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
</nav> 


<section class="prod-hero"></section>
 <div class="wrapper">
    <section class="tile js-panel pad0">        
        <section id="features" class="nav-section prod-panels"> 
        <h2>Features</h2>
        </section>
        <section class="prod-panels">   
            <h2>New section</h2>
            <p>I do not want this section to appear in the nav</p>
        </section>

        <section id="claims" class="nav-section prod-panels">   
            <h2>Claims</h2>
        </section>
        ....    

   </section>
 </div>
```

**JS**:

```
var homeH = $( window ).height(),
pH = [];
var clicked = false;
// create array with panel heights
for (var s=0; s<5; s++) { 
   var po = $(".js-panel section.nav-section:eq("+s+")").offset();
   pH.push( Math.round(po.top) );
};
$( window ).scroll(function() {
 if (clicked === true) {
    return;
 } else if (clicked == "fuzzy") {
    clicked = false;
    return;
 }
 // toggle top menu
 if ( $( window ).scrollTop() < homeH/2) {
   $("#prod-menu ul li").removeClass("sel");
   $("#prod-menu").css("top", "-55px");
 } else {
   $("#prod-menu").css("top", "0");
 };
 $("#prod-menu ul li").removeClass("sel");

 // toggle top menu selection
 var st = $( window ).scrollTop();
 for (var i=4;i>=0;i--) {
   if ( st > pH[i] ) { 
     $("#prod-menu ul li:eq("+i+")").addClass("sel");
     break;
   }
 };

});

// animating anchor link scrolling
// snippet from css-tricks 
// css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/smooth-scrolling

$("a[href*=#]:not([href=#])").click(function() { 
  if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
   var liEle = $(this).parent("li");
   var target = $(this.hash);

   target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
   if (target.length) {
      clicked = true;
      $('body').animate({
       scrollTop: target.offset().top-50
      }, 700, function() {
        clicked = "fuzzy";
        $("#prod-menu ul li").removeClass("sel");
        liEle.addClass("sel");
      });

    return false;
   }
 }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Wikunia this is very close. It works perfectly on scrolling, however when you click on the anchor links, the previous link is selected. For example, if I click on 'reviews', then 'guides' shows as the selected state. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Hi @Adam really not a favorite solution but that one should be fixed now! No idea how to make it better but there should be a better way :D

Comment: Try this: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OPeMEq . I have only changed Wikunia's code a little.

Answer (score 2):

i have forked your code pen, tried to use another approach

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/myNRzR

```
    var homeH = $( window ).height(),
    pH = new Array();

// create array with panel heights

   $(".js-panel section").each(function(){
      var elm = $(this);
       var po = elm.position();
      pH.push({
        top : Math.round(po.top),
        element : elm
      });
    });


pH.sort(function(a, b) {
    if (a.top > b.top)
      return -1;
    if (a.top < b.top)
      return 1;
    // a doit être égale à b
    return 0;
});
var ord = {
  hasScrolled : true,
  locked : false
};
var ticker = function(){

  if(ord.hasScrolled){
    var menu = $("#prod-menu"),        
     actTop = $( window ).scrollTop(), 
     level = actTop + menu.height();
    ord.locked = true;
    ord.hasScrolled = false; 
    for(var i in pH){
      var o = pH[i];

      if(level > o.top && level < (o.top + o.element.height())){
        menu.css("top", "0");
        $("#prod-menu ul li").removeClass("sel");
        $("#prod-menu").find("a[href='#"+ o.element.attr("id") +"']").parent().addClass("sel");
        break;
      }
    }





    ord.locked = false;
  }
}

setInterval(ticker, 250);

$( window ).scroll(function() {
 ord.hasScrolled = true && !ord.locked;
  // toggle top menu


});

// animating anchor link scrolling
// snippet from css-tricks 
// css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/smooth-scrolling

$("a[href*=#]:not([href=#])").click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
      var target = $(this.hash);
      target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
      if (target.length) {
        $('html,body').animate({
          scrollTop: target.offset().top-50
        }, 700);
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
```

by using a ticker instead of the onScrollEvent : it's work just fine.

It would be better if you wrap all that in a plugin.